# Compiler error "cannot find symbol - class ENUM_NAME"

Tags: java, enums

I have defined an enum. When I try to write:

```
private ENUM_NAME variableName;
```

as the instance variable of a class, the compiler tells me:

```
cannot find symbol - class ENUM_NAME
```

which is preventing me from continuing.

I am using the BlueJ IDE, if that matters.
All files are contained within one package, and are in the same folder on my computer.
I began with the enum inside of another class (a test driver for my working class), and I got the stated error in my working class. Then I tried making the enum its very own class, and I got the same error.

The test driver class:

```
public class BicycleMainClass
{
    enum BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM {STANDARD, RACER, MOUNTAIN, BMX};
    //main method below
}
```

The "working" class:

```
public class BicycleClass
{
    private BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM bicycleType;
    //this line gives me the error "cannot find symbol - class BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM"
}
```

I would expect it to compile without error, because enums are a valid variable type. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared your enum type as a [nested type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of `BicycleMainClass`, so you need to include the outer type when referring to it:

```
class BicycleClass
{
    private BicycleMainClass.BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM bicycleType;
}
```

Another solution is simply to declare your enum type as a [top-level type](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/nested,-inner,-member,-and-top-level-classes):

```
public enum BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM {
    STANDARD, RACER, MOUNTAIN, BMX;
}
```

Then you can refer to it directly:

```
private BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM bicycleType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import statement for  BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM.
Please make sure you use proper package name while adding the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with static import
for nested enums

or

try this **private BicycleMainClass.BICYCLE_TYPE_ENUM bicycleType;**

Hope this will help..